# Filtering List from a List

Tags: c#, linq, filter

Bottom line is I would like a linq statement that returns the same list as the code below.

I feel like this is possible and I feel like I got very close before I gave up and just spelled out what I wanted with more lines of code.

Although I would love and appreciate anyone that could demonstrate what I'm looking to achieve for the future and to replace what I have.

```
public ObservableCollection<VarItem> IndexChannels 
{
    get
    {
        ObservableCollection<VarItem> filtered = new ObservableCollection<VarItem>();

        filtered.Add(indexChannels.First());//add Disabled no matter what

        //add the cur channels selected index if it isn't already disabled
        if (!filtered.Contains(indexChannels.FirstOrDefault(i => i == CurChannel.IndexChannel)))
        {
           filtered.Add(indexChannels.FirstOrDefault(i => i == CurChannel.IndexChannel));
        }

        foreach (PdioChannelModel ch in channels)
        {
           //if the channels mode isn't q-decode or quad index add its Number as an index
           if (ch.Mode.Value != "Q-Decode" && ch.Mode.Value != "Quad Index") 
           {
              filtered.Add(indexChannels.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == ch.Number));
           }
        }
        return filtered;
    }
}
```

Basic structure of VarItem

public class VarItem
   {
      public int ID { get; private set; }
      public string Value { get; private set; }
      public Dictionary MetaData { get; private set; }

```
  public VarItem(int id, string value)
  {
     this.ID = id;
     this.Value = value;
     MetaData = new Dictionary<string, string>();
  }
```

example master list contains VarItems:

-1, "Disable"

1, "Channel 1"

2, "Channel 2"

3, "Channel 3"

Filtered list should always contain `VarItem(-1, Disabled)`. It should also contain the `VarItem` where the `ID` matches `CurChannel.IndexChannel`and lastly it sould contain any `VarItem`s where the ID matches any `PdioChannelModel.Number` where `PdioChannelModel.Mode.Value != "Q-Decode" or "Quad Index"`

If I missed any detail needed let me know. If I confused you and wrote to much or need clarification just let me know as well.

Comment: Are you trying to replace all that code with a single bit of linq or jsut the foreach bit because while you could probably write that as one command the fact it is effectively doing three different things (default, current, filtered) probably means it is more readable to keep those things separate. The foreach could probably be pretty easily changed to an `filtered.AddRange` and a Where followed by a Select if that's all you wanted but again I'd be inclined to "if its not broken, don't fix it". Though of course as a learning exercise for next time its still useful... :)

Comment: Some questions. Where does `channels` come from? Is it the same type as `indexChannels`? Is `IndexChannels` (capital I) a typo? And is it guaranteed that `indexChannels.First()` is always the "Disabled" item? I think this can be achieved by filtering and sorting.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to generate a list of the items you want to add and pass that to the constructor.

We know for sure we want the first item in indexChannels, and the current channel selected index if it's there, so that part is pretty easy - just a `new List<VarItem>`.

Next you want to add all the index channels who have IDs that match the Numbers of the channels whose Modes are not Q-Decode or Quad Index. So for that I'd use a `Union` to join this with the first list.

And finally, since `FirstOrDefault` returns `default(VarItem)` for default values, we can just remove those at the end, and we can throw a `Distinct` in there as well to ensure that we don't have duplicates:

```
get
{
    return new ObservableCollection<VarItem>((
        new List<VarItem>
        {
            indexChannels.First(),
            indexChannels.FirstOrDefault(i => i == CurChannel.IndexChannel)
        })
        .Union(channels
            .Where(ch => ch.Mode.Value != "Q-Decode" &&
                         ch.Mode.Value != "Quad Index")
            .Select(ch => indexChannels.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == ch.Number)))
        .Where(varItem => varItem != default(VarItem))
        .Distinct());
}
```

Just for the record, I would never do this in production code. Any failures in that statement will be a huge pain to debug. Generally doing one statement per line is easier for others to read and easier to debug when one line fails.

Answer (score 0):

Do you care if you add `null` values to your `ObservableCollection`? If you want to exclude `null` values, then `FirstOrDefault` is not the right method to use inside your `foreach`. If, on the other hand, you know for sure than every channel `Number` property will exist *at least once* in `indexChannels`, then just use `First`. That way if your assumption is wrong (and `Number` does not match any `ID`), then `First` will throw an exception, which is probably what you want instead of a `NullReferenceException` later on that will be harder to debug. If, in addition, you know for sure that every channel `Number` property will exist only once in `indexChannels`, then use `Single`, so you get an exception when this second assumption is violated. That again, is easier to debug than some unexpected behavior later.

Here's an example solution:

```
return new ObservableCollection<VarItem>(
    indexChannels
    .Take(1)
    .Union(indexChannels.Where(i => i == CurChannel.IndexChannel).Take(1))
    .Union(channels
        .Where(c => c.Mode.Value != "Q-Decode" &&
                    c.Mode.Value != "Quad Index")
        // The following line could be turned into
        // .Select(c => indexChannels.First(i => i.ID == c.Number))
        // OR
        // .Select(c => indexChannels.Single(i => i.ID == c.Number))
        // OR 
        // .SelectMany(c => indexChannels.Where(i => i.ID == c.Number))
        // depending on how many channels in indexChannels 
        // are expected to match each Number property.
        .Select(c => indexChannels.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ID == c.Number))
);
```